# MeshBasicMaterial() color not recognized

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

Here is my code to render a red coloured mesh (hex:0xff3300) into the scene. But my every try is failed.I only keeping on seeing only a white mesh nomatter what hex color have I  specified into THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()

```
<div style="height:500px;width:500px;background:black"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="three.js"></script>
<script>
var div=document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(div.offsetWidth,div.offsetHeight);
div.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var scene=new THREE.Scene();
var camera=new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,div.offsetWidth/div.offsetHeight,1,4000);
camera.position.set(0,0,3);
scene.add(camera);
var geometry=new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1,1);
var mesh=new THREE.Mesh(geometry,new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(0xff3300));
scene.add(mesh);
renderer.render(scene,camera);
</script>
```

Please help me

Comment: `new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff3300})`